# Copy data into postgres from Redshift using Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Is there an efficient way to copy a table from redshift to postgres using nodejs, couldn't find any concrete examples

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be any utility pre-written. the process that you must adopt (set up) for anything more than just a few rows is:

1. Push data to S3
2. Use AWS Copy command (using SDK) to copy from S3 to Redshift
3. Transform data in Redshift (optional)